# 'Argument 'Start' must be greater than zero. ' exception when using Mid function

Tags: vb.net

When I use Mid function

```
MsgBox(Mid(RXdata, RXdataLen - 3, 1))
```

in vb.net, I always get the following message

```
Additional information: Argument 'Start' must be greater than zero.
```

I think it is impossible since the RdataLen is 9, the 'Start' is definitely larger than 9.  RXdata is the data that I read from SerialPort.

Any thought on how come it happens?

Thanks

Comment: You would be much better off in the long run using modern NET methods like `SubString` in place of those legacy VB functions.  If the length of `RXdata` is 0 to 2 then the start ( `RXdataLen - 3`) will be less than zero.  You are not checking the length.

Comment: `I think it is impossible since the RdataLen is 9, the 'Start' is definitely larger than 9`  Your exception is telling you something else.

Comment: As @Plutonix says, you would be better off using the modern string methods such as `SubString`. However, that won't help if you don't get the arguments right. The error is telling you that the 'start' argument is zero, so despite what you posted, `RXdataLen` must be 3. Set a breakpoint on the `MsgBox` statement and verify that.

Comment: When you get the exception, you just have to hold the mouse over `RXdata` to see what it is (and how long).

Comment: Thank you guys.  There is typo in my question.  I wanted to say 'start' is definitely larger than 0 rather than 9.  I agree with you that substring is better.  RXdataLen is fixed with is 9 and I verified with Msgbox() so that it should not give me this error message but indeed it did.. weird..